# Prediction of regression coefficients with XGBoost

Tags: regression, survival, boosting, nonparametric, weibull-distribution

I am doing survival analysis. There is a dataset of items `(id, group_id, observed lifetime, censorship status)`, each item belongs to a certain group. Each item is unique, but this uniqueness is unobservable, unpredictable and uncontollable, so we cannot base our predictions on it. Let's call that dataset `items dataset`. Each group has features easily obtainable as a separate dataset of groups `(group_id, group_features)`. Let's call that dataset `groups dataset`.

One of the main goals of the research is to be able to predict expected lifetime of items of a certain group from its features and to be able to explain why (I utilise SHAP for that). In fact order predictions make more sense, but it is the next stage of the research. At the current stage I just want pretty accurate lifetime expectations.

I have combined the data from `items dataset` by `gid` and got a set of subdatasets of failure times belonging to each group. I have fitted a Weibull regression against each of those subdatasets of and got ρ and λ modelling survival of each group. I call this operation an `aggregation`. It maps `items dataset` to the dataset `(gid, ρ, λ, #items with that gid in items dataset)`. Then I add there the data from `groups dataset`.

Then I try to fit a model predicting ρ and λ with XGBoost using the objective `reg:squarederror` and count of items in each group as a weight.

Then I predict the expected lifetime of an item of a group using the formula

$$E(Weibull(ρ=XGB<ρ>(...), λ=XGB<λ>(...)))$$,

where `XGB<ρ>(...)` means calling the trained XGBoost model for the column `ρ` passing it the group's feature vector.

Unfortunately,

- CV error (only XGBoost one) is tremendous even after 10000 iterations of hyperparameter optimization
- the composite model predicts values which are completely mad. For example typical non-censored lifetime of an item is about 1500 days, but the composite model predicts 2 days as an expectation.

  1. Am I doing the right thing? Is it possible at all to predict regression coefficients and then use them to predict expectation? Should I use count of items in groups as weights?
  2. Should I modify XGBoost objective plugging there hessian and gradient of expectation of Weibull distribution and try to predict the expectation directly by feeding it directly with `items dataset` augmented with the data from `groups dataset` and having a gradient for each item individually, rather than just predicting Weibull distribution coefficients and then expectation from them? Can I expect them to have the comparable performance?

Comment: If your feature set is identical, what is the point of using XGBoost? You essentially just estimate a baseline hazard. If you don't trust the Weibull assumption use a non- or semi-parametric model for the baseline hazard. XGBoost is only advantages for complex feature relationships with the outcome

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The identical items are items of the same group. There is a dataset, it contains items of different groups. I fit Weibull regression for each group, get the coefficients. I call it `aggregation`, it transforms 2 datasets : one of items (id, gid, lifetime, censorship) and one of groups (gid, group features) into the dataset of groups (gid, group features, ρ, λ). Features non-specific to a group but specific to an item are unobservable. The goal is to predict expected lifetime for the groups not in the dataset at all. Against the resulting dataset the model is fitted.

Comment: It seems like you are throwing away a lot of information by lumping together cases into groups and then doing group-wise weighted fitting. An earlier version of this question indicated that within each group having common feature vectors there were some censored and some un-censored cases, and that there were different failure times among the un-censored cases within each group. Those differences within groups are important for survival modeling. Details about numbers of cases, events, groups, and why you expect squared error to be useful to minimize in survival analysis would help.

Comment: 1. Doesn't Weibull regression deal to censorship and intragroup difference itself? Isn't the data about censorship and individual items lifetimes redundant for XGBoost model since all the instances of the same group have the same feature vector?

Comment: 2. I really expected squared error to help, but without lot reasons for that. The reasoning was following: I am not training a neural network where interaction between layers mean a lot. I am training a Weibull regression which is meant to describe the group of items alone. XGBoost is used not to model survival function, but to model common structure between groups. So if we assumme the lifetimes follow Weibull distribution, what we need to predict lifetime expectation are correct params for it. Since the etalon params are already fitted, all we need is to predict them correctly.

Comment: Params are reals, so L2 loss. I may have needed an another loss, but it is too much work to do it before I get sure that it is absolutely needed: impl in python will be too slow, implementing a new objective in C++ for XGBoost means some debugging and testing, so I definitely give L2 loss a try .

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you are actually trying to achieve. Could you edit your question stating clearly what the objective of your analysis is (what are you trying to find out) and what are the features/targets, ideally without reference to Weibull regression and XGBoost first. Then explain how you tried to solve your objective using Weibull model and XGBoost.

Comment: You cannot predict the Weibull parameters independently with an xgboost for each separately since they are highly correlated parameters. In other words as you change one parameter, in order for the mean to stay reasonable, the other parameter must change as well. You are likely predicting unreasonable combinations of parameters even if each xgboost produces a reasonable estimate of an individual parameter.

Comment: @jsk, thanks for the answer. What do you advise me to do first, to try to tune XGBoost objective or to try to implement it via a very shallow neural network (I have an AMD GPU, so no tensorflow)?

Comment: Not sure the best way to do this, but here's a thread which may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540123/muti-output-regression-in-xgboost

Comment: Thanks for the advice, though the stuff just fits separate models for each variable - the same thing I do. I have tried to modify the objectibe first. I have set the objective to KL-divergence between 2 Weibulls, but I have problems of gradients and hessians being inf after some iterations because some points on trajectory  (λ ~ 1e-3 .. 1e-5) lie close to the forbidden region ( ρ<=0 || λ<=0) .

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you have information on survival of individuals as a function of group membership, but don't have detailed information about the features associated with each individual. You do, however, have information about covariates associated with each of the groups.

First, you've done separate Weibull models on each group, which (as @adibender noted in comments) is simply modeling the baseline hazard for each group. Although Weibull modeling can often be useful, it's not clear whether you have even documented that Weibull models are appropriate for your data. For example, Weibull models don't allow for non-monotonic hazards as a function of time, so one potential explanation for your difficulty is that Weibull modeling is not appropriate for your data.

Second, parametric Weibull modeling of survival data, even when appropriate, is typically done with all cases at once. The model would identify a value of $\lambda$ common to all groups along with the differences among groups with respect to ρ. I can't prove that your approach (separate Weibull models for each group and then modeling the Weibull coefficients as a function of covariate value associated with groups) is necessarily wrong, but it doesn't seem to comport with the way that survival analysis in typically done.

If your interest is in the relations of the covariates to outcome, I see two ways to proceed.

One way would be modeling survival as a function of group first, then modeling group membership as a function of covariates. If all the information you have about survival is directly related to group membership, then the most direct survival model would be based on group membership. You then identify covariates most associated with the longest/shortest-survival groups.

The second way to proceed would be to accept the limitations of your data and simply assign to each individual the covariate values associated with that individual's group. That would remove the group membership from the analysis and allow direct (although clearly imprecise) modeling of how the covariates are related to outcome. If your `group dataset` has information on the probabilities of features associated with each group, you could treat this as a type of missing-data problem, using [multiple imputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-imputation/info) to obtain several sets of imputed data and thus incorporate the uncertainty in the individual-covariate associations.

With either of those approaches you would not have to use a parametric model, Weibull or otherwise. You would be able to test the appropriateness of the models (e.g, test for proportional hazards) in a way that your present approach doesn't seem to allow.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. In my case groups are models of equipment so memberships in groups are rigid and known in advance. Covariates are technical specifications of a model. Item in `items dataset` is a device which lifetime is known. The matters is complicated by the fact that not all possible groups are  in the dataset and I try to predict expectation of survival for groups not present in dataset. If I understand right, you propose to just merge the datasets, making groups features items features and fit a model against that. I have already tried that without much success,

Comment: , with big memory overhead and very bad performance and even with some numerical problems causing XGBoost to predict NaNs if the dataset exceeds some count of items.  Though comparing to Weibull, Cox non-PH (with XGBoost predicting partial hazards instead of linear regression) worked pretty well (0.7 concordance, though the predictions were complete junk, it had predicted high lifetime expectation for some models known as faulty).

Comment: I have tried to optimize that too by using harmonic mean, but that "optimized" model resulted in concordance 0.5. About imputation, I don't quite understand how it can help me here. I used imputation for missing data when a model (like stock lifelines Cox PH) disallows missing data (XGBoost was used for imputation), but witnout much success, XGBoost-powered Cox is the best model I have managed to achive on this task, and unfortunately that model is junk.

Comment: @KOLANICH you could consider an extension of my first suggestion to cover groups not present in the data set. Model survival by group for present groups (combining all in a single analysis), and develop a multinomial model for predicting group membership from covariate values. Covariate values for new equipment models would then be mapped to group-membership probabilities. Those probabilities could allow some weighted-average of group survival predictions. The failure of my second suggestion, however, makes even that unlikely to work well; you might need to model interactions among covariates.

Comment: Doesn't XGBoost model interactions?

Comment: @KOLANICH as you have fixed covariate values for each group my suggestion of multiple imputation wouldn't work. Survival analysis will always provide some "junk" answers, as 0.7 concordance (not so bad in clinical studies) means you get the order of failure wrong for 30% of pairs. Understanding how the model failed for a particular type of equipment might help refine the model. Consider standard Cox regression on the merged dataset, with some interaction terms chosen based on your knowledge of the subject matter, to get a possibly more heuristic appreciation of how the models are failing.

Comment: @KOLANICH the depth of XGBoost interactions is set by the `max_depth` parameter. A setting of 1 would produce an additive model without interactions. If you used the default setting of 6 you might be overfitting (and certainly are using a lot computational resources). Overfitting might be contributing to your difficulties. Consider pulling back on the interaction depth.

Comment: Yes, I know. All the parameters are tuned with crossvalidation, except trees count. Count of trees is set to 10, with that count of trees the rest of hyperparams are optimized (performance is always measured with crossvalidation), after that count of trees is optimized incrementing it from 1 to 100 (again measuring with crossvalidation), fixing all other hps, usually ~30 trees are used. The model with ~0.7 had max_depth = 5. Then hps are saved and used to fit a model. So I guess cv should protect me from overfitting.